# jQuery optgroup and option value in multiple select box

Tags: jquery, select, optgroup

Please refer to my first question by this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155086/jquery-populate-optgroup-for-second-selectbox-dynamically), thanks to @A.V for helpfulness,

The script which provided is work great in fact, but there is an issue in the giving name for `option value` and `optgroup`, please go http://jsfiddle.net/NZ6tY/7/ for more specific action, **group 1-1** is working nice with option value and optgroup label without **space**, **comma** or **slash**, where the rest is unworkable, can anyone please give a solution? I must having a long text in the option value and optgroup label as necessary info.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing your jsfiddle, the problem with it is the selector for the optgroup.

It currently looks like this:

`$('optgroup[label='+somelabel+']');`

Which does work fine, however when `somelabel` contains spaces or special characters, they interfere with the selector.
To remedy this, simply enclose `somelabel` with quotes, like this:

`$('optgroup[label="'+somelabel+'"]');`

I forked your fiddle and made the update (line 33): http://jsfiddle.net/S7NkB/

**Edit:** please note that if `somelabel` contains quote characters you would want to escape or replace those or it will break again.